# How do I get the input text (not just the value) from a Material for Web select component?

Tags: material-design

In the docs, it specifies how to get the index and data-value, but not the input text:

```
import {MDCSelect} from '@material/select';

const select = new MDCSelect(document.querySelector('.mdc-select'));

select.listen('MDCSelect:change', () => {
  alert(`Selected option at index ${select.selectedIndex} with value "${select.value}"`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes you have more than one MDCSelect to initiate

```
import {MDCSelect} from '@material/select';

const selectElements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-select'));

selectElements.forEach((selectEl) => {
  const select = new MDCSelect(selectEl);

  select.listen('MDCSelect:change', (el) => {
    const elText = el.target.querySelector(`[data-value="${select.value}"`).innerText;
    console.log(`Selected option at index ${select.selectedIndex} with value "${select.value}" with a label of ${elText}`);
  });
});
```